# Converting Hugging Face Transformer Text Embeddings Back to Text

Tags: python, pipeline, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

Is there a method for converting Hugging Face Transformer embeddings back to text?

Suppose that I have text embeddings created using Hugging Face's [ClipTextModel](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/clip#transformers.CLIPTextModel) using the following method:

```py
import torch
from transformers import CLIPTokenizer, CLIPTextModel

class_list = [
    "i love going home and playing with my wife and kids",
    "i love going home",
    "playing with my wife and kids", 
    "family",
    "war",
    "writing",
]
    
model = CLIPTextModel.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-large-patch14")
tokenizer = CLIPTokenizer.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-large-patch14")
    
inputs = tokenizer(class_list, padding=True, return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)
hidden_state = outputs.last_hidden_state
embeddings = outputs.pooler_output
```

My embeddings are in the variable "embeddings". Questions:

1. Is it possible for me to convert my embeddings back to the input strings in "class_list"? To be precise: If I sent the embeddings to a person who had no foreknowledge of the list of original strings; what steps would they need to take to extract the list of the original strings?
2. If so, how can I do this?

Comment: You may not get exact text back. [Here](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate) some strategies are discussed.

Comment: Tried that unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

That greedy search using a LLM might work if you do a beam search but at each leaf node you then generate an embedding for what you have generated so far down each branch and then compared the distance of that branch with the embedding your searching for... now that I write it out, it strikes me as a bit like the A* algorithm! You would stop when your within some distance threshold or you start to get further from the target? I assume if it is guided by the LLM it would be grammatical?

Might give it a shot when i have a moment...

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a general method to covert a text embedding into the original text directly. In causal LLM, text are generated by a multi-class classifier which takes the previous embedded as input and output the probabilities of then next token. And in BERT-like text encoders,if your text embeddings are extracted from `[CLS]` token, you won't be able to reconstruct the original text.

However, in BERT if the text embeddings are simply the `last hidden states` of the **last encoder layer**, then you should be able to reconstruct your text sequence with the corresponding trained decoder.

Anyway, I don't think there is a rule that "encoded texts must be able to be decoded back". You could regenerate the text using the CLIP embeddings with a trained opensource multi-modal model, but no garantee the results are identical to your inputs.